# Get pictures links from Google Search

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to get the pictures links from a searched link through google and this is my try

```
Sub Test()
Const sURL As String = "https://www.google.com.eg/search?q=baby&sxsrf=ALeKk01tyfvvxyYjaC0YctjxaY0RlvPnuw:1586804351129&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjB77TtiuboAhUl5uAKHR5KA2wQ_AUoAXoECBQQAw&biw=1280&bih=881"
Dim http As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

Set http = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

With http
    .Open "Get", sURL, False
    .send
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With

Dim post As Object, i As Long

Set post = html.querySelectorAll(".mM5pbd .bRMDJf")

For i = 0 To post.Length - 1
    Debug.Print post.Item(i).innerHTML
Next i

Stop
End Sub
```

First I got the post.Length only 20 while I expect about 300 
Second I can't get the correct link for the picture as it seems it is base64 encrypted or something similar (I am not sure)
How can I get the real links for the picture and get all the links for all the pictures related?

I think it is solved for one point

```
    Set post = html.querySelectorAll("a.VFACy.kGQAp")

For i = 0 To post.Length - 1
    Debug.Print post.Item(i).href
Next i
```

But how to get all the links instead of the 20 links only?
** The links are not totally right, for example I got this link

```
https://www.fool.com/taxes/2018/03/27/are-you-having-a-baby-here-are-the-tax-breaks-you.aspx
```

While the correct link is

```
https://g.foolcdn.com/editorial/images/466737/new-parents-holding-newborn-baby-mom-dad-father-mother.jpg
```

** I tried using IE

```
Sub TestIE()
Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate "https://www.google.com.eg/search?q=baby&sxsrf=ALeKk01tyfvvxyYjaC0YctjxaY0RlvPnuw:1586804351129&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjB77TtiuboAhUl5uAKHR5KA2wQ_AUoAXoECBQQAw&biw=1280&bih=881"
    While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

    'querySelectorAll("a.VFACy.kGQAp")
    Dim post As Object

    Set post = ie.document.querySelectorAll("a.VFACy.kGQAp")

    For j = 0 To post.Length - 1
        Debug.Print post.Item(i).innerHTML
    Next j
Next
End Sub
```

But in results I got the same innerhtml for all

```
<div class="sMi44c lNHeqe"><div class="WGvvNb" dir="ltr">Baby colic - Wikipedia</div><div class="fxgdke"><span dir="ltr">en.wikipedia.org</span></div> 
</div>
```

Is using QuerySelectorAll different when dealing with IE?

** Another try

```
        Dim post As Object

    Set post = ie.document.querySelectorAll(".bRMDJf img")
    Dim r As Long

    For j = 0 To post.Length - 1
    r = r + 1
        Cells(r, 1).Value = post.Item(i).getAttribute("src")
    Next j
```

Now I got 100 but not the links, it is base64 encryption for the pictures, moreover I found out the output is the same for all the pictures. I could decrypt the pictures but the quality is low .. and I got only 100 .. How can I increase the number of results and get the correct links?

[image]

Comment: The page uses lazy loading. You will need to scrollby and use a browser.

Comment: So there is no way of escaping using the browser and in this case, will I be able to use QuerySelectorAll? ... And I couldn't get the correct link for the pictures.

Comment: There is no way to avoid using a browser unless there is an API from google for images. And yes, with ie you can use querySelectorAll method of .document

Comment: There are good existing answers on SO/Code review by at least '@SIM and '@alecxe. Can't remember if python and/or vba. Easy enough to see logic and use as a template.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you help me as I couldn't get the correct link for each picture? I have put example of the link I got and the link I expect.

Comment: Try using a proper web scraper instead of trying to write your own: https://scrapy.org/

Comment: @QHarr I have tried using IE and posted my try in the main post but I didn't get the links at all.

Comment: @QHarr any help in this topic?

Comment: I don't think scraping google is allowed and to aid in this html will change frequently. Look for relationships between tags in particular rather than relying on attributes (unless you can be sure they are pretty static over time).

Comment: I have no clue at all. I have tried a  lot but couldn't reach a solution.